# Getting trimmed output of a ssh command

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, terminal

When trying to run a remote, I get a trimmed output. For example, after running:

```
ssh host@server top -b -c -n 1
```

I get:

```
4789 user    20   0  359m 249m 3464 S  0.0  3.3   0:06.83 worker.rb:
```

Where the original out is much longer. Why?

Comment: This question should probably be in [SU] instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

top tries to be useful and crops the output to your terminal width. Try `ssh -t host@server top -b -c -n 1` to force ssh to create a pseudo-tty (that should have the same width as your real one).

Or alternatively something like `ssh host@server COLUMNS=100 top -b -c -n 1`.

Answer (score 0):

1. the first line of *top* should not be

   ```
   4789 user    20   0  359m 249m 3464 S  0.0  3.3   0:06.83 worker.rb:
   ```

There are some header lines in top [see below snippet]

2. Check the output of other commands. Say `ls -l`.

I am getting it fine
Both remote host and localhost are running Ubuntu in my case. What about your case?

It's worthwhile to check the environment. Is your ssh authentication automated? Mine is automated.

```
user1@ubuntu1:~/workspace/$ssh -l test 172.16.210.49 top -b -c -n 1
top - 19:20:46 up 6 days,  4:04, 21 users,  load average: 0.05, 0.17, 0.09
Tasks: 360 total,   1 running, 357 sleeping,   2 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.2%us,  0.3%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.3%id,  0.2%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   3551720k total,  3382900k used,   168820k free,   290424k buffers
Swap: 10402808k total,        0k used, 10402808k free,  2311780k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND            
27858 test      20   0  2704 1220  812 R    4  0.0   0:00.03 top -b -c -n 1    
 1305 lp        20   0  2072  596  460 S    2  0.0 128:47.18 /usr/sbin/lpd -s   
 1588 tech      20   0 38420  12m 9.8m S    2  0.4  14:46.55 /usr/lib/vino/vino-
    1 root      20   0  2844 1732 1224 S    0  0.0   0:00.93 /sbin/init         
  ... and lot more follow.........
```